# Joining tables and getting a count of specific record

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am having two tables say table_a and table_b with following structure.

**table_a** : ID(primary key), value_one

**table_b**: ID, value_two

Note that id in table_b is not primary and contains multiple records to same id.

now i want a third table which displays a record for every id in table_a with columns being

id column_count

the column _count will display number of records (count) in table_b with value_two = 'c'. and i want to iterate this to all records of table_a.

For example lets say our **table_a** is like this:

```
id   value_one
1   20
2   40
3   50
```

**table_b**

```
id value_two
1   10
1   20
1   10
2   40
2   10
3   40
3   10
```

I want records with value_two = 10 so my new table would look like

```
id   count
1   2
2   1
3   1
```

Since id 1 has two records with value_two = 10 and id 2 and id 3 have one record each with value_two = 10

Comment: looks like homework. what have you tried already? what, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: I tried joining the tables but i am not able to simultaneously get the count of each corresponding record while joining. If u can help me code exactly as i demonstrated in the example it would be great

Comment: i won't just give you the answer, this is something that you're looking to learn. You do need to join the tables, use a count on the t2 field and group by the t1 field to return your result

Comment: *Since id 1 has two records with value_two = 10 and id 2 and id 3 have one record each with value_two = 10* What if `table_a` contains a record which have no according records (accounting the condition or at all) in `table_b`? Does the output must contain this record's `id` with zero value?

Comment: yes @Akina it should contain that record as well with 0 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this uses a correlated subquery:

```
select a.id,
       (select count(*) from table_b b where b.id = a.id and b.value_two = 10) as cnt_10
from table_a a;
```

Another method uses a `left join`:

```
select a.id, count(b.id)
from table_a a left join
     table_b b
     on b.id = a.id and b.value_two = 10
group by a.id;
```

In your example data, this works:

```
select b.id, count(*)
from table_b b
where b.value_two = 10
group by b.id;
```

This is equivalent under the following circumstances:

- All ids in `a` are in `b`.
- All ids have at least one value of `10`.

If these two conditions are true, then use this simpler query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select id, sum(value_two = 10) as count
from table_b tb
group by id;
```

If you want matching `id`s then add `INNER JOIN`. This will show `0` count whereas `value_two = 10` not found. You can add where clause to find only `value_two = 10` count.